# Is it possible to test the type in a generic function?

Tags: java, generics

I would like to make a generic function that deserializes a byte array into a type specified by the caller.
I feel that a really intuitive way to call such a function would look something like:

```
byte[255] myData = [...]
String myUnserializedString = new Packet<String>(myData).unpack();

byte[4] myInt = [...]
int myUnserializedInt = new Packet<Integer>(myInt).unpack();
```

As a user, this is the kind of interface I'd like to be offerred. The problem is that (obviously) each type has to be unserialized in a different way. This means that the unpack() method has to perform some kind of reflexive test to choose the right way to interpret the raw bytes.

After trying for a little while to write a prototype for such a class, I am beginning to feel that Generics may not be the right tools for that kind of design.

Are they?

Comment: Can you show your attempted code?  It might be possible to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define Packet as an interface, and have one implementation for each type of data.

```
public interface Packet<T> {  
   T unpack(byte[] data);  
}  

public final class StringPacket implements Packet<String> {  
     public String unpack(byte[] data) {  
         // Implementation...  
     }  
}  

 // Similar classes for other types...
```

Comment: +1. different data type requires different unpacking code, so subclassing is a natural way to go.

Comment: if using `ObjectInputStream` then that is not needed at all - the stream already has this functionality in it.

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution, which seems to be the "right" way to do it. Yishai's solution is closer to the kind of interface I was looking for, but extensibility has to be taken into account as well: subclassing will allow users to define their own packet types. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not providing any real type safety here, but it could provide some casting convenience. However, the obvious way to do this is to have the unpack method do all the work:

```
 public <T> T unpack(Class<T> klass) {
      return klass.cast(unpackedData);
 }
```

And call it like this:

```
  new Packet(myData).unpack(String.class);
```

Even if you could twist generics into getting it done the way you want (I think you can with an unsafe cast, which is all Class.cast is doing anyway), this is the more standard idom and avoids you doing your own unsafe casting. Either way, you are saying that the client knows the type, as it sets the Generic parameter in your example.

Comment: well, if the user has wrong expectations (either as .class or with generics), a ClassCastException will be thrown.

Comment: @Bozho, sure, that is why I said you aren't getting any real type safety, just casting convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If they **have to** be handled in a different way, then Packet is not truly generic!

There's nothing wrong with

```
class StringPacket extends Packet {
 // ...
}
```

or

```
class StringPacket implements Receivable, Sendable {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
class Packet<T> {
   private byte[] bytes;
   // consructor here
   public T unpack() {
       (T) readObject(bytes);
   }
}
```

`readObject(..)` can rely on `ObjectInputStream`

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'll be using a homemade serialization protocol, so the Objects won't be serialized in a readObject-compatible way.